# Android DownloadManager class

Tags: android, class, download-manager

I need to download a large file . I need to use `DownloadManger` class for api 9 or higher version . But I wish my download to continue even if User pauses the `Activity` or presses `Back` ... or user  kills the `Activity`. Once he starts the downloading process it should stop only after finishing that respective download. If meanwhile network connectivity breaks the downloading should resume from where it stopped,i.e, should not start from the beginning .

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried and what problems have you come across? Some code please?

Comment: see the file is being downloaded while the i have register an intent for action download completed if i pause the activity by press any event key then I need to unregistered the receiver in onpause and reregister it on resume if mean while my download take place when  n where i have unregistered the receiver how do I came to know it is completed

Comment: Ah, I understand the question now. Detailed answer below.

Comment: Patience my friend. It takes time to type out the answers :)

Comment: dear @curioustechizen I unfortunately down voted your answer please reedit your answer so that i can upvote my your answer .........

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to depend only on an `Activity` for this use case. There are two options:

#### Option 1

1. Use a `Service` in addition to your `Activity`. In your `onPause()`, start the `Service` and in your `onResume()` of your Activity, stop the `Service`.
2. The `Service` itself should also register for the `ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` broadcast.
3. If you receive the broadcast when your Activity is in the background, i.e., in your `Service`, you can post a notification or toast or whatever that the user clicks to get back to your `Activity`. You should also register for `ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED`.

#### Option 2

1. Simply create a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for the `ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` broadcast.
2. In the `onReceive()` you can do whatever you want when the download is complete. Again, if you Activity is already in the foreground you can directly update your UI. Else, user clicks the `Notification` and you can handle that in `ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED`.

Comment: option two would be good i will check more then other wise implement it

Comment: This answer has been down-voted. I don't mind at all if it is accompanied with a reason explaining the down-vote.

Comment: Zip file? You never mentioned anything about zip file in the question. Are you sure this comment is for the right question?